# ERR WAIT cannot be used with slave instances Redisson

Tags: redis, redisson, distributed-lock

<redisson.version>3.16.3</redisson.version>
readMode: SLAVE

Not sure why am I seeing this error.

caused by: org.redisson.client.RedisException: ERR WAIT cannot be used with slave instances. Please also note that since Redis 4.0 if a slave is configured to be writable (which is not the default) writes to slaves are just local and are not propagated.. channel: [id: 0x90c58500, L:/172.16.189.108:43192 - R:10.112.94.132/10.112.94.132:15003] command: (WAIT), promise: RedissonPromise [promise=ImmediateEventExecutor$ImmediatePromise@35eeb35e(incomplete)], params: [1, 1000]
at org.redisson.client.handler.CommandDecoder.decode(CommandDecoder.java:370)
at org.redisson.client.handler.CommandDecoder.decodeCommandBatch(CommandDecoder.java:271)
at org.redisson.client.handler.CommandDecoder.decodeCommand(CommandDecoder.java:210)
at org.redisson.client.handler.CommandDecoder.decode(CommandDecoder.java:137)
at org.redisson.client.handler.CommandDecoder.decode(CommandDecoder.java:113)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:502)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:366)

Comment: Can you share Redis config files?

Comment: I think you specified slave as master host. Redisson tries to write into it and fails. Use master host only.